# Simple streaming parser to extract lines

Tags: c#

It is meant to be given strings over time and output all `NewLine` delimited substrings. The ColumnReader is meant to be a solution for `Delimiter`-separated-value files, like CSV or TSV.

```cs
using System;

namespace fbstj
{
    public sealed class LineReader
    {
        public string NewLine { get; set; }

        string _buffer = "";

        public void Parse(string text)
        {
            _buffer += text;

            var lastline = _buffer.LastIndexOf(NewLine);
            if (lastline == -1)
                return;

            var lines = _buffer.Substring(0, lastline).Split(NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            _buffer = _buffer.Substring(lastline);

            foreach (var line in lines)
                Receive(line);
        }

        public event Action<string> Receive = (line) => { };
    }

    public struct ColumnReader
    {
        public readonly string Delimiter;
        public readonly LineReader Reader;

        public ColumnReader(string newline, string delimiter) : this()
        {
            Reader = new LineReader { NewLine = newline };
            Delimiter = delimiter;
            Receive += (columns) => { };
            Reader.Receive += _receive_line;
        }

        private void _receive_line(string line)
        {
            Receive(line.Split(Delimiter.ToCharArray()));
        }

        public event Action<string[]> Receive;
    }
}
```

My main use-case is reading lines from a `SerialPort`:

```
var parser = new IO.LineReader { NewLine = port.NewLine };
port.DataReceived += (o, e) => parser.Parse(port.ReadExisting());
parser.Receive += (line) => { };
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like they used to be fields and then you made them properties:

```
public readonly string Delimiter;
public readonly LineReader Reader;
```

IMHO that means they should get a getter and setter, like this:

```
public string Delimiter { get; private set; }
public LineReader Reader { get; private set; }
```

---

[String.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) is culture-specific, so consider using a [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. The `readonly` are just arbitrary, no real decision behind them. I've replaced my ColumnReader with a different implementation.

Comment: What do you mean "they used to be fields and then you made them properties"? They *are* fields in the first code block.

Comment: @mjolka [Fields should (almost always) be kept private to a class and accessed via get and set properties.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c) Here's Microsoft: [use fields only for variables that have private or protected accessibility. Data that your class exposes to client code should be provided through methods, properties and indexers.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

Comment: @BCdotWEB yes but the answer sounds like you're saying `public readonly string Delimiter;` declares a property, when it actually declares a field.

Comment: @mjolka True, but to me the intent is that of a property.

Comment: could you expand how I would improve the `LastIndexOf` stuff. Maybe on [my next question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82575/simple-streaming-parser-to-extract-columns)

Comment: @FallingBullets Use an appropriate [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx); which one is appropriate for your case is something you need to determine.