# Simple streaming parser to extract columns

Tags: c#

In reply to [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/82473/47369) I rewrote `ColumnReader` and would like more suggestions

```cs
using System;

namespace R2D.IO
{
    public sealed class LineReader
    {
        public string NewLine { get; set; }

        string _buffer = "";

        public void Parse(string text)
        {
            _buffer += text;

            var lastline = _buffer.LastIndexOf(NewLine);
            if (lastline == -1)
                return;

            var lines = _buffer.Substring(0, lastline).Split(NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            _buffer = _buffer.Substring(lastline);

            foreach (var line in lines)
                Receive(line);
        }

        public event Action<string> Receive = (line) => { };
    }

    public sealed class ColumnReader
    {
        public string Delimiter { get; set; }
        public string NewLine
        {
            get { return reader.NewLine; }
            set { reader.NewLine = value; }
        }

        private LineReader reader = new LineReader();

        public ColumnReader()
        {
            reader.Receive += (line) => Receive(line.Split(Delimiter.ToCharArray()));
        }

        public event Action<string[]> Receive = (columns) => { };
    }
}
```

My main use-case is reading lines from a `SerialPort`:

```
var parser = new IO.LineReader { NewLine = port.NewLine };
port.DataReceived += (o, e) => parser.Parse(port.ReadExisting());
parser.Receive += (line) => { };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Split(NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

If `NewLine` is `"\r\n"`, then this will split the input on every `\r` and every `\n`. You then take care of the resulting empty strings by specifying `RemoveEmptyEntries`. But this means that if the input actually contains an empty line, you won't receive it.

To fix that, you can instead use:

```
Split(new[] { NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Is that passing an array of strings?

Comment: @FallingBullets Yeah, it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419475/the-type-or-namespace-textfieldparser-could-not-be-found) and attach the serial port to a `StreamReader` and use that as input for the `TextFieldParser`.

Comment: Indeed `TextFeldParser` is a more sensible way of doing this for CSV files. I came across it a few weeks ago and then promptly forgot about it and developed this. Thank's for reminding me. I would still like comments on my code though more than a solution to the problem.